# Regex match returning unexpected results

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying a regex match, but am getting unexpected results. What am I doing wrong?

```
$text = "one two three?four five six?";
preg_match("~(.+?)(?:\?)?~", $text, $match);

print_r($match);
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => o [1] => o )
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => one two three? [1] => one two three )
```

Comment: Why do you want to capture the question mark for the first match, but not for the second?

Comment: @Rizier123 I just need to capture the first string that ends or doesn't end in a question mark. There are, of course, more to my regex, that I'm not showing here. But it's this part that I need to complete, so I'm only showing this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `?` next to non-capturing group which makes that non-capturing group as optional. Since the `?` is optional, `(.+?)`
 non-greedy pattern should match and capture only the first character.

```
preg_match("~(.+?)\?~", $text, $match);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vT5jL4/3)

Comment: Note that op uses preg_match not preg_match_all

Comment: I want to and need to make the question mark optional. There are more to my regex, than the example that I'm showing above. The example, is just the part that I need to solve.

Comment: I need to capture one string that is 1 or more characters long, and that ends or doesn't ends with a question mark. But I need the regex to consider the ends with a question mark first, before considering the doesn't end with a question mark. Right now, the regex is considering the doesn't end with a question mark first. Which is why it's capturing only one character, since I'm telling it to be non-greedy. But I need it to capture up to the first question mark, which is why I added the ? to make it non-greedy.

Comment: Oh. I'm such an idiot. Of course, just put the (.+)? like that.